# How does nitinol "remember" it's shape?

Tags: material-science

Nitinol is a metal that will snap back into the shape it was forged in if warmed after being messed with. I am kind of lost as to how this is possible, in particular what it even means for nitinol to remember it's shape.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_titanium#Mechanism

Answer (score 2):

the classic ( & simplified) answer is that the interatomic bonds which existed when nitinol was originally formed are not broken when it is later bent- they are stressed. heating the sample allows for slippage within the crystal structure of the material and furnishes the opportunity for the original bonds to relax- and pull the material back into its original shape.